# NuGet equivalent of Maven Install

Tags: nuget

I'm wondering how to install a package locally so I can test it without having to run a CI job, just like what `mvn install` does. Is this possible with NuGet?

I know there's `nuget add` but that requires many manual steps (build the package, copy it over into the proper package directory, etc.). I couldn't find much else, is there anything NuGet (or IDEs) offer to make this easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote up two bash functions to help out with this kind of thing:

```sh
pack () {
    dotnet pack -c Release -o ./packages -p:PackageVersion="$1"
}


add () {
    for nupkg in packages/*.nupkg
    do
        nuget add "$nupkg" -source ~/.nuget/custom-local-packages
    done
}
```